# android: RecyclerView stopSmoothScrolle() null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

[Closed] read my last comment below.

I have a PagerView with some fragments, it was working but today unexpectedly crashed. The log it shows only this, i tried to catch the error with breakpoint but i didn't get anything.

Do you have any ideas ?

Here is my log

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.stopSmoothScroller()' on a null object reference
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.stopScrollersInternal(RecyclerView.java:1229)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.stopScroll(RecyclerView.java:1221)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.java:1426)
            at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:13560)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2837)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2834)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4220)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4193)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:4124)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.removeView(ViewPager.java:1326)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1055)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.detachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1290)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:724)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:488)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: It's seem that your recycle view doesn't set LayoutManager yet when recreate. You should reveal more where you setLayoutManager and your view pager adapter code

Comment: I have fragments and recycler view is on fragments.

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) vv.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_v2);

       // LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        setRecyclerAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: What supportv7 revision do you use? I look into the code of RecyclerView 22.2.1 and they already added a null check.

Comment: [I fix my error by reading this][1] read third comment at the link below.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26702633/4643928